# ネットワーク上のノードを表すオブジェクトにメソッド呼び出しでアクセスしたい

Tags: java, ruby, python, c++, network

ネットワーク上のノードを表すオブジェクトに，メソッド呼び出しでアクセスするようなコードの書き方はありませんでしょうか？

例えば，Python で書くと，

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.hoge = 'hogehoge'

    def do_something(self):
        n = Node('127.0.0.1', 12345)
        self.hoge = n.get_hoge()

    def get_hoge():
        return self.hoge
```

Java で書くなら，

```
class Node {
    private String ip;
    private int port;
    private String hoge;

    public Node(String ip, int port) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
        this.hoge = "hogehoge";
    }

    public doSomething() {
        Node n = new Node('127.0.0.1', 12345);
        this.hoge = n.getHoge();
    }

    public getHoge() {
        return this.hoge;
    }
}
```

このような書き方ができるクラスを作りたいです．
要するに，相互に通信を行う `Node` クラスからソケット API のコードを隠蔽したいということです．

言語は問いません．
何かいい書き方はありませんでしょうか？
また，不可能なら不可能と教えていただけると助かります．
よろしくお願いします．

Comment: RPC(リモートプロシージャコール）という単語で検索すれば色々出てきます。まあ今時はWebAPIとして作るほうが言語を問わず使えるので一般的だと思います。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ネットワーク越しのメソッド呼び出しのことを「RPC」、それをオブジェクト指向にしたものを「分散オブジェクト」といいます。古くはCORBA、WindowsならDCOM、JavaならJavaRMIなどがあります。それ以上のことは私は詳しくありません。「分散オブジェクト ｛言語名｝」等で検索してみるといいでしょう。

私見ですが、最近そういうのはあまり流行っていないような気がします。なんでもHTTPリクエストのAPIで片付けてしまうような。

その手のライブラリは、登場しては消えていく、を繰り返していて、これと言って定着しているものが、ほとんど無いような印象です。

Comment: HTTP越しのやつでさえ、SOAPとかJSON-RPCとか星の数ほどありますね。そしてどれも消えていった。結局RPCは諦めてステートレスなREST APIだけが残ったと。同期型のRPCにはプログラミングモデルが単純になる以外にメリットがない気がします。

Answer (score 3):

Pythonでしたら標準ライブラリの SimpleXMLRPCServer を使用してXML-RPC サーバーを実装してみてはどうでしょうか。

http://docs.python.jp/2/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html#simplexmlrpcserver-example

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます．Python でネットワークシミュレータを書いているのですが，紹介いただいた xmlrpc は pure-python だったので，これを参考にしつつ，オーバヘッドを減らすように実装していきたいと思います．

Answer (score 3):

Ruby の場合は、標準ライブラリの dRuby を使うと、ネットワークの向こうにあるオブジェクトのメソッドを普通のオブジェクトのメソッド呼び出しのように使うことができます。

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.3.0/library/drb.html

http://dev.classmethod.jp/server-side/ruby-on-rails/druby_distributed_object_other_procerss/